# Select specific rows on pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a column called bmi (Body Mass Index) containing int values

[image]

I have to separate the  values in bmi column into Under weight, Normal, Over weight and Obese based on the values. Below is the loop for the same

[image]

However I am getting an error. I am a beginner. Just started coding 2 weeks back.

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, it is helpful if you post text/code instead of screenshots. Regarding your question, what is your goal? Using `pandas` dataframes, you generally want to avoid loops. Here, you could e.g. create a column 'classification' which you fill based on the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, using a for loop in pandas is usually a bad idea. Pandas allows you to manipulate data easily. For example, if you want to filter by some condition:

```py
print(df[df["bmi"] > 30])
```

will print all rows where there `bmi>30`. It works as follows: `df[condition]`. Condition in this case is "bmi" is larger then 30, so our condition is `df["bmi"] > 30`. Notice the line `df[df["bmi"] > 30]` returns all rows that satisfy the condition. I printed them, but you can manipulate them whatever you like.

Even though it's a bad technique (or used only for specific need), you can of course iterate through dataframe. This is not done via `for l in df`, as df is a dataframe object. To iterate through it you can use [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row["bmi"] > 30)
        print("Obese")
```

Also for next time please provide your code inline. Don't paste an image of it

If your goal is to separate into different labels, I suggest the following:

```py
df.loc[df[df["bmi"] > 30, "NewColumn"] = "Obese"
df.loc[df[df["bmi"] < 18.5, "NewColumn"] = "Underweight"
```

`.loc` operator allows me to manipulate only part of the data. It's format is [rows, columns]. So the above code takes on rows where bmi>30, and it takes only "NewColumn" (change it whatever you like) which is a new column. It puts the value on the right to this column. That way, after that operation, you have a new column in your dataframe which has "Obese/Underweight" as you like.
As side note - there are better ways to map values (e.g pandas' `map` and others) but if you are a beginner, it's important to understand simple methods to manipulate data before diving into more complex one. That's why I am avoiding into explaining more complex method

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, As mentioned in the comment you should post text/code instead of screenshots.

You could do binning in pandas:

```
bmi_labels = ['Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese']
cut_bins = [18.5, 24.9, 29.9, df["bmi"].max()]
df['bmi_label'] = pd.cut(df['bmi'], bins=cut_bins, labels=bmi_labels)
```

Here, i have made a seperate column (bmi_label) to store label but you could can do it in same column (bmi) too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated.